# How many confirmation do i have to wait before i can spend the inputs I already received?

Tags: transactions, confirmations, doublespend, unconfirmed-transactions

Can I spend Inputs with 0 confirmations?? If I could, are there some restrictions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Can multiple transactions transferring the same bitcoin be done in one block?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1726/5406), [Can an output be spent in the block in which it is contained?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/30485/5406); related: [Order of transactions within a block](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/23035/5406)

Answer (score 1):

If the input is coinbase transaction, you can't spent it until it get 100 confirmations. Relevant code is [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/1d9d314573ee48f6f51107265f1cf1fa9e36c998/src/consensus/consensus.h#L14) 
If the input is not a coinbase transaction, you can spend it by creating a raw transaction [How To Create A Raw Transaction](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#simple-spending)

However, receiving input with 0 confirmation is not recommended.

> Zero-confirmation transaction vulnerability: accepting
>   zero-confirmation transactions (transactions that have not yet been
>   included in a block) from somebody you do not trust is still not
>   recommended, because there will always be ways for attackers to
>   double-spend zero-confirmation transactions. However, this release
>   includes a bug fix that makes it a little bit more difficult for
>   attackers to double-spend a certain type ("lockTime in the future") of
>   zero-confirmation transaction.

Comment: what is a coinbase transaction?

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of freshly mined coins, it is possible to spend unconfirmed funds - though it depends on which wallet you use.  The bitcoin-core, cli version, will by default only spend funds with at least one confirmation, but it's possible to override, i.e. using the sendfrom command:

```
sendfrom "fromaccount" "tobitcoinaddress" amount ( minconf "comment" "comment-to" )
```

Set minconf to 0 and you're done.

Be aware of the trust issue; if you receive funds from someone you don't trust and send the coins further to someone that trusts you, you could put your reputation on line if the original sender pulls a double-spend.

If the original transaction carried a low fee and that's the reason why it hasn't been included in the blockchain yet, the new transaction may help to get it confirmed faster

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Blockchain.info's wallet, you need to wait for 1 confirmation before spending it out. If your wallet has more than the amount you want to spend and that amount is not currently in any transaction or is un-confirmed, you can spend your coins easily.